# DropdownButton with int items not working, it does not select new value

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to create DropdownButton widget with int items, but it does not work as expected.

This is the code:

```
DropdownButton<int>(
    hint: Text("Pick"),
    items: <int>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map((int value) {
      return new DropdownMenuItem<int>(
        value: _number_tickets_total,
        child: new Text(_number_tickets_total.toString()),
      );
    }).toList(),
    onChanged: (newVal) {
      setState(() {
        _number_tickets_total = newVal;
      });
    })
```

The problem is that the widget never gets the value selected. I always see the "hint" text even when I choose a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are missing is `value` attribute of the DropdownButton. When that value is null, it will show the hint, otherwise latest selected value.

The values that you are using in the drop-down item is irrelevant from the whole list, that's why you should just pass them the related information. I modified your code with the value attribute below.

```
      DropdownButton<int>(
        hint: Text("Pick"),
        value: _number_tickets_total,
        items: <int>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map((int value) {
          return new DropdownMenuItem<int>(
            value: value,
            child: new Text(value.toString()),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (newVal) {
          setState(() {
            _number_tickets_total = newVal;
          });
        });
```